# Craft Commerce - Create Order from Control Panel

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, control-panel, order

We've been looking around to get some info for this feature but didn't find anything yet and wanted to ask here in case we are missing something.

Is there a way to create an order from the Control Panel?

We are working on a project that needs to track orders not done via the website and will need the ability to create manual orders from the CP but this feature doesn't seem to exist in Craft Commerce.

Does anyone know if there is a 3rd party plugin that we might have missed that allows this functionality? Or if this is a feature that might be considered in the future scope of Craft Commerce?

Thanks heaps,
Alby

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this from the control panel unfortunately.

It's been said a bunch of times it's on the roadmap, and it's an oft requested feature.

I don't think there is a generalised plugin for this yet.  I doubt there will be as it's coming to core.

It's certainly possible to write one, but it would be a fair bit of work.

(You could quickly hack something together in the form of a form that lists all your products and uses MultiAdd to add them to a cart in one go...but you'd still have to go through checkout to complete the order.  https://github.com/engram-design/MultiAdd

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. We'll take a look at the Multi Add form and see what we come up with. Do you have any idea if there's an ETA for this feature to go into core?

Comment: My guess is it will come with Commerce 2 (and Craft 3) - but totally a guess.  I get the impressions features as such are not being added to Commerce until P & T get over all that needed update work...